# simple mssql count not working - not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, count

I am new to SQL, I have done basic MySQL

So I have a query working, joining 3 tables fine, however I want to count occurrences of values in the field OrderItem.ItemNumber

So I tried this:

```
Select
  [Order].dDispatchBy,
  [Order].dProcessedOn,
  [Order].Source,
  [Order].ExternalReference,
  [Order].nOrderId,
  [Order].bProcessed,
  [Order].CreatedBy,
  [Order].CreatedDate,
  [Order].dReceievedDate,
  [Order].nStatus,
  [Order].ReferenceNum,
  [Order].SubSource,
  OrderItem.fkOrderID,
  OrderItem.fkStockID,
  OrderItem.nQty,
  OrderItem.ItemNumber,
  OrderItem.fkLocationId,
  OrderItem.fkCompositeParentRowId,
  OrderItem.ChannelSKU,
  OrderItem.fkStockItemId,
  OrderItem.fkStockItemId_processed,
  OrderItem.DispatchStockUnitCost,
  OrderItem.ShippingCost,
  OrderItem.SalesTax,
  Count(OrderItem.ItemNumber) As CountMe
From
  [Order] Inner Join
  OrderItem
    On [Order].pkOrderID = OrderItem.fkOrderID Left Join
  StockItem
    On OrderItem.fkStockID = StockItem.pkStockItemID
Where
  Convert(DATETIME,Floor(Convert(FLOAT,[Order].dProcessedOn))) =
  Convert(DATETIME,Floor(Convert(FLOAT,GetDate())))
```

And this works fine if I removed the line:

`Count(OrderItem.ItemNumber) As CountMe`

I get the error if I do not remove this line.

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column >'Order.dDispatchBy' is invalid in the select list because it is not >contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You are selecting bunch of non-aggregate columns along with a Count aggregate. Add the non-aggregate columns in `Group by`

Comment: You need Group by clause with all column in select list

Comment: Add sample source data and desired output of the query you're attempting to implement and I'm sure you'll see the problem. If you are returning each `OrderItem` row, what would be `Count(OrderItem.ItemNumber)` in each row?

Comment: I'm doubting that this is the result set you are looking for, but ok.

Comment: its an order lines table, with one line per product and products can be dupicated

so 

orderline1,product1
orderline2,product2
orderline3,product1
orderline4,product1
orderline5,product1

i want a result set, would shows me 

product1,4
product2,1

should i be using count

Comment: What do you want to group the records by?

Answer (score 0):

You should add group by with all the columns mentioned in the "select" except aggregate function. Try this,

```
SELECT [Order].dDispatchBy
    ,[Order].dProcessedOn
    ,[Order].Source
    ,[Order].ExternalReference
    ,[Order].nOrderId
    ,[Order].bProcessed
    ,[Order].CreatedBy
    ,[Order].CreatedDate
    ,[Order].dReceievedDate
    ,[Order].nStatus
    ,[Order].ReferenceNum
    ,[Order].SubSource
    ,OrderItem.fkOrderID
    ,OrderItem.fkStockID
    ,OrderItem.nQty
    ,OrderItem.ItemNumber
    ,OrderItem.fkLocationId
    ,OrderItem.fkCompositeParentRowId
    ,OrderItem.ChannelSKU
    ,OrderItem.fkStockItemId
    ,OrderItem.fkStockItemId_processed
    ,OrderItem.DispatchStockUnitCost
    ,OrderItem.ShippingCost
    ,OrderItem.SalesTax
    ,Count(OrderItem.ItemNumber) AS CountMe
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN OrderItem ON [Order].pkOrderID = OrderItem.fkOrderID
LEFT JOIN StockItem ON OrderItem.fkStockID = StockItem.pkStockItemID
WHERE Convert(DATETIME, Floor(Convert(FLOAT, [Order].dProcessedOn))) = Convert(DATETIME, Floor(Convert(FLOAT, GetDate())))
GROUP BY [Order].dDispatchBy
    ,[Order].dProcessedOn
    ,[Order].Source
    ,[Order].ExternalReference
    ,[Order].nOrderId
    ,[Order].bProcessed
    ,[Order].CreatedBy
    ,[Order].CreatedDate
    ,[Order].dReceievedDate
    ,[Order].nStatus
    ,[Order].ReferenceNum
    ,[Order].SubSource
    ,OrderItem.fkOrderID
    ,OrderItem.fkStockID
    ,OrderItem.nQty
    ,OrderItem.ItemNumber
    ,OrderItem.fkLocationId
    ,OrderItem.fkCompositeParentRowId
    ,OrderItem.ChannelSKU
    ,OrderItem.fkStockItemId
    ,OrderItem.fkStockItemId_processed
    ,OrderItem.DispatchStockUnitCost
    ,OrderItem.ShippingCost
    ,OrderItem.SalesTax
```

Comment: thank you, it now runs the query, however all the results are 1 (in the count column) and they is more then 1 of certain rows, i have even change the column it checks in to ChannelSKU, but still i only get 1, its very odd

Comment: I know you are counting OrderItem.ItemNumber but I am not sure based on which column combination.

Comment: date sample
------------
order1.productcode1,etc,etc
order2.productcode2,etc,etc
order3.productcode2,etc,etc
order4.productcode1,etc,etc
order5.productcode1,etc,etc
order6.productcode1,etc,etc
order7.productcode1,etc,etc

i would want to know the below

results sample
--------------
order1.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order2.productcode2,etc,etc,2
order3.productcode2,etc,etc,2
order4.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order5.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order6.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order7.productcode1,etc,etc,5

so because productcode1 was seen 5 times in the whole record set, it would say 5

Comment: its an order lines table, with one line per product and products can be dupicated

so 

orderline1,product1
orderline2,product2
orderline3,product1
orderline4,product1
orderline5,product1

i want a result set, would shows me 

product1,4
product2,1

should i be using count

Answer (score 0):

### data sample

order1.productcode1,etc,etc
order2.productcode2,etc,etc
order3.productcode2,etc,etc
order4.productcode1,etc,etc
order5.productcode1,etc,etc
order6.productcode1,etc,etc
order7.productcode1,etc,etc

i would want to know the below

### results sample

order1.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order2.productcode2,etc,etc,2
order3.productcode2,etc,etc,2
order4.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order5.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order6.productcode1,etc,etc,5
order7.productcode1,etc,etc,5

so because productcode1 was seen 5 times in the whole record set, it would say 5

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out, i had to make a view first and then used that view

Select
  COUNT(*),
  StockItem.ItemTitle
From
  view_name Left Join
  StockItem
    On view_name.ItemNumber = StockItem.ItemNumber
Group By
  StockItem.ItemTitle;

Does anyone know another way to make a temp table, my server does not allow
or replace on views and i can not delete

i guess i want to do sql in steps, so 1 result is not so complex